# Undo a mysql UPDATE command

Tags: mysql

I was trying to do an update on the MySQL server and accidentally forgot to add an additional WHERE clause which was supposed to edit one row.

I now have 3500+ rows edited due to my error.

I may have a back up but I did a ton of work since the last backup and I just dont want to waste it all because of 1 bad query.

Please tell me there is something i can do to fix this.

Comment: I bet you wished you transactions

Comment: unfortunately, if you didn't do a back up I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: I just did and found that its OFF.

Comment: How can i rollback if it was enabled ? Just want to know to tackle future problems if any.

Comment: I really hope you were working on a development or testing environment, and not on production.

Comment: What is that "backup" thing everyone keeps refering too? ¬¬ (obviously joking - I just made this same mistake on a non critical production DB that has no backups. Hating myself for it. It's been more than 10 years since the last time I did something this stupid.)

Comment: almost 5 years now, there never goes a day without checking my update statements twice :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you committed your transaction, it's time to dust off that backup, sorry.  But that's what backups are for.  I did something like that once myself... once.

Answer (score 12):

Just an idea - could you restore your backup to a NEW database and then do a cross database query to update that column based on the data it used to be?

Comment: I have never done this before? Any suggestions on how to do it ?

Comment: For restoring - I would have my DBA do it (I'm a developer, not a DBA).  For cross database query - I'm not a mySQL person so I don't know the details. But in Oracle, we first grant permission to "select" on the appropriate table in schema1 to schema2.  Then we prefix the table with schemaName.  So select * from schema1.tablename.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing.

Despite this you can be glad that you've got that learning experience under your belt and be proud of how you'll now change your habits to greatly reduce the chance of it happening again.  You'll be the 'master' now that can teach the young pups and quote from actual battle-tested experience.

Comment: I'm glad it happened at this stage and ill be extra cautious hereafter. Although the impact is not that serious, it still affects me. But nevertheless, it was a good learning experience.

Comment: Hi @Naveen. Did you manage to solve the problem. Forgot the where clause and my head is hot. My backup is not so recent.

Answer (score 10):

There is only one thing that you can do now is **FIX YOUR BAD HABIT**, it will help you in future. I know its an old question and OP must have learned the lesson. I am just posting it for others because I also learned the lesson today.

So I was supposed to run a query which was supposed to update some fifty records and then `MySQL` returned THIS `48500 row(s) affected` which gave me a little heart attack due to one silly mistake in `WHERE` condition :D

### So here are the learnings:

1. Always check your `query` twice before running it but sometimes it won't help because you can still make that silly mistake.
2. Since Step 1 is not always helpful its better that you always take backup of your `DB` before running any query that will affect the data.
3. If you are lazy to create a backup (as I was when running that silly query) because the DB is large and it will take time then **at least use** `TRANSACTION` and I think this is a good **effortless** way to beat the disaster. From now on this is what I do with every query that affects data:

I start the `Transaction`, run the `Query`, and then check the results if they are OK or Not. If the results are OK then I simply `COMMIT` the changes otherwise to overcome the disaster I simply `ROLLBACK`

```
START TRANSACTION;
  UPDATE myTable
  SET name = 'Sam'
  WHERE recordingTime BETWEEN  '2018-04-01 00:00:59' AND '2019-04-12 23:59:59'; 
ROLLBACK;
-- COMMIT; -- I keep it commented so that I dont run it mistakenly and only uncomment when I really want to COMMIT the changes
```

Comment: The way you keep "COMMIT" in the snippet so you remember it's an important part of the task, but leave it commented out so you don't copy/paste it accidentally, is good evidence of your rigourous and diligent thinking. I applaud you! Keep it up!